# Can't disable autostart via the windows 8 taskmanager

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, task-manager

I have the following problem:

I have a user with is not a administrator and see the following:

[image]

then I start the taskmanager as a administrator via the command line and see the following:

[image]

**What I have to do to disable the autostart? As a user I cant. As an admin I dont see it.**

Comment: always use autoruns instead of this ugly limited taskmgr: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are loading the task manager as administrator so effectively you are seeing the administrators autostart list not the user you are logged in as (and it would appear the administrator does not have anything setup here).

The only way round this from my knowledge is to temporarily add the user to the local administrators group on the PC then log off and back on, disable the autostart task, remove the user from the administrators group log off and back on.

Answer (score 1):

As CharlesH said, you could give the user temporary admin rights.
Or you could use the program [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) which has a dashboard for disabling and enabling start up items.